# My minute variable is displaying 900 minutes ahead

Tags: java, datetime, java-time

My end result is something like: 918 minutes past 3 o'clock on July
 9, 2017, 1st Era.

918 minutes is weird, and I'm not willing to do that much math to figure out what time it is. Here is my code below.

```
package learn;

import java.time.*;
import java.time.temporal.*;

class time {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();

    int minute = now.get(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_DAY);
    int hour = now.get(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int day = now.get(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int month = now.get(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR);
    int year = now.get(ChronoField.YEAR_OF_ERA);
    int era = now.get(ChronoField.ERA);

    if (hour < 12) {        
        System.out.println("Good morning you sack o' shit."); 
    }
    else if (hour < 17) {
        System.out.println("Get a job hobo. ");
    }
    else {        
        System.out.println("Night night, jobless");
    }

    System.out.print("It's: ");
    if (minute != 0) {

    System.out.print("" + minute + " ");

    System.out.print( (minute != 1) ? "minutes" : "minute");
    System.out.print(" past");

    }
    System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.print( (hour > 12) ? (hour - 12) : hour);
    System.out.print(" o'clock on ");

    switch (month) {        
        case 1: System.out.println("January"); break;
        case 2: System.out.println("February"); break;
        case 3: System.out.println("March"); break;
        case 4: System.out.println("April"); break;
        case 5: System.out.println("May"); break;
        case 6: System.out.println("June"); break;
        case 7: System.out.println("July"); break;
        case 8: System.out.println("August"); break;
        case 9: System.out.println("September"); break;
        case 10: System.out.println("October"); break;
        case 11: System.out.println("November"); break;
        case 12: System.out.println("December"); break;
       }
    System.out.println(" " + day + ", " + year + ", " + era + "st Era.");

    }

}
```

Comment: I refer you to the [ChronoField Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html).  Go through all of the available fields and select the ones you really need.

Comment: You know 1 hr is 60 min. I'd suggest using The Unix Epoch.

Comment: You're using MINUTE_OF_DAY instead of MINUTE_OF_HOUR. Or just call now.getMinute()

Answer (score 2):

You are using `ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_DAY`, which is not what you want (3:18 PM will be equivalent to the 918<sup>o</sup> minute of the day because it already has passed 918 minutes from the start of the day (midnight) until 3:18 PM).

The field you want is `ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR`, although `LocalDateTime` already has methods to get the fields you need:

```
int minute = now.getMinute();
int hour = now.getHour();
int day = now.getDayOfMonth();
int month = now.getMonthValue();
int year = now.getYear();
int era = now.toLocalDate().getEra().getValue();
```

To get the month name in English, there's also a built-in method:

```
import java.util.Locale;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;

String monthName = now.getMonth().getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [`ChronoField` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html), here is the list of fields you appear to need:

`MINUTE_OF_HOUR`
The minute-of-hour.

`HOUR_OF_DAY`
The hour-of-day.

`DAY_OF_MONTH`
The day-of-month.

`MONTH_OF_YEAR`
The month-of-year, such as March.

`YEAR`
The proleptic year, such as 2012.